# Angular 7 & Jest & Babel Integration over Jasmine/Karma - AngularSnapshotSerializer.js in the snapshotSerializers option was not found

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, babel-jest

Steps to integrate of Jest & Babel with Angular 7+:

1. Run the following commands to install:

   ```
   # Remove Jesmin/Karma
   npm remove karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter karma-jasmine karma-jasmine-html-reporter

   npm uninstall jasmine @types/jasmine

   rm ./karma.conf.js ./src/test.ts

   # Install jest    
   npm install --save jest@24.9 @angular-builders/jest@7 @types/jest@24 jest-preset-angular@8 

   # Install babel
   npm install --save-dev babel-jest babel-polyfill
   npm install --save @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-flow @babel/preset-typescript
   ```
2. On `package.json`, added the following code:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     ...
     ...
     "test": "ng test",
     "test:watch": "jest --watch",
     ...
     ...
   }
   ...
   ...   
   "jest": {
     "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
     "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
       "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Also, updated the following on the `angular.json`:

   ```
   ...
   ... 
   "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
   ...
   ...
   ```

   Replace with:

   ```
   ...
   ... 
   "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
   ...
   ...
   ```
4. Create the `<root>/setupJest.ts` with below content:

   ```
   import 'jest-preset-angular';
   ```
5. Create the `<root>/babel.config.js` with below content:

   ```
   module.exports = function(api) {

       const presets = [
           '@babel/preset-typescript',
            [
               "@babel/preset-env", {
                   "targets": {
                       "node": "current"
                   }
               }
           ],
           '@babel/preset-flow'
       ];

       return {
           presets,
       };
   };
   ```
6. And, finally tried running the `ng-test` from a terminal, however, I was stuck with the following error (see picture below):
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

7. Eventually, managed to fix the issue by adding the file `<root>/src/jest.config.js` with below content:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       "transform": {
           "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "ts-jest",
           "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
       },
       moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json'],
       moduleNameMapper: {
           '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
           '^app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
           '^assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
           '^environments/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/environments/$1',
       },
       transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx)'],
       snapshotSerializers: [
           'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularSnapshotSerializer.js',
           'jest-preset-angular/build/HTMLCommentSerializer.js',
       ],
   };
   ```

Thereafter, ran `ng test` again and can see the test running thru.

I hope it helps!